# Spring boot application with Azure AD throws Reply URL does not match

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, saml

I have a spring boot application integrated with Azure AD SAML login. I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory) sample to achieve this. It works fine in localhost but on deployment to a prod url, it keeps giving below error

[image: Reply Url does not match]

the redirect uri that I see in the authorization request URL starts with http. This is contradictory because Azure App Registration does not allow to configure any non https URLs and only exception is localhost.

In order to match URLs, I tried editing App Registration's manifest in Azure portal to make it http. Now, it seems URLs match but then I get below error:

[image]

I have also tried setting https URL both on azure portal and application.properties using "azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template" as mentioned in stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269391/spring-security-with-azure-ad-doesnt-redirect) but that also does not work.

I have also gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713926/the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-urls-configured) post but that also didn't help.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please check your Tomcat server following this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64423135/13308381). Another method is adding `server.forward-headers-strategy=native` in applications.properties to avoid starting with http.

Comment: @PamelaPeng , Thank you for your reply. Adding server.forward-headers-strategy=native did not help. I also added other lines in application.properties from the link you shared                                                            
azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template= https://xxx.xxx.xxx/login/oauth2/code/azure
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirecturi=https://xxx.xxx.xxx/login/oauth2/code/azure
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirecturi=https://xxx.xxx.xxx/login/oauth2/code/azure
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
server.forward-headers-strategy=native

Comment: Thanks @PamelaPeng, adding all the lines from the link you shared solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the error of redirecting to `https` but the redirect_uri in request still starts with `http`, there are two similar issues:

**1.** The HTTPS requests terminate at the proxy and the proxy then uses    HTTP protocol to communicate to your Tomcat server. You will face this if you deploy your code on cloud providers like App Service. Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi/64423135#64423135).

In **application.properties**:

```
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://yourappurl.net/login
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://yourappurl.net/login
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects=true
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*
```

**2.** Add `server.forward-headers-strategy=native` in applications.properties. Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389955/13308381). For more about this setting, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629968/13308381).